# How to #define based on iOS version?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c-preprocessor

I have a `Constants.h` file in my app, where I `#define` app-wide things for easy access later. I'm having a hard time, though, `#define`ing based on iOS version. Here's what I've tried:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_7_0

#define kHamburgerImage [UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal_menu_icon_portrait_ios7.png"];

#else

#define kHamburgerImage [UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal_menu_icon_portrait.png"];

#endif
```

<sup>Just because it says iOS 7 in there doesn't mean this is under NDA, O closers!</sup>

Which works fine - *for iOS 7*. When I run my app on iOS 6, however, the `#define` is still the iOS 7 one - it seems as though the `#ifdef` is never taken into account.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You can't do this. The iOS version needs to be a runtime decision, not a compile time decision.

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry! I guess it doesn't work - it works for normal code, but not #defines...

Comment: Right, unless you are doing this to be able to build the code with two different versions of Xcode, you need to use runtime checks, not compile time checks. Both `#if` and `#define` are compile time features.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using compile-time checks, you need runtime checks. This means you can't use `#define`. I suggest using a static variable that is initialized at runtime based on the version of iOS. Below is an example if you only need the value in a single file.

Some .m file:

```
static UIImage *kHamburgerImage = nil;

+ (void)initialize {
    // This assumes you only support iOS 6 and later - adjust as needed
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion hasPrefix:@"6"]) {
        kHamburgerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal_menu_icon_portrait.png"];
    } else {
        kHamburgerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal_menu_icon_portrait_ios7.png"];
    }
}
```

Edit: Since these need to be globals, you should do this:

Constants.h:

```
extern UIImage *kHamburgerImage;

@interface Constants
@end
```

Constants.m:

```
UIImage *kHamburgerImage = nil;

@implementation Constants

+ (void)initialize {
    // This assumes you only support iOS 6 and later - adjust as needed
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion hasPrefix:@"6"]) {
        kHamburgerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal_menu_icon_portrait.png"];
    } else {
        kHamburgerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal_menu_icon_portrait_ios7.png"];
    }
}

@end
```

But this suffers from a problem. Unless you take specific steps, accessing these globals could result in `nil` pointers. They only get initialized if the class is actually referenced. I suggest that as the first line of your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` you do:

```
[Constants class];
```

This ensures the initializer is called and the constants are setup before you use them anywhere else in your code.

Comment: Soo... Change my `Constants.h` file into a `.m` file?

Comment: If these are used in a global file then you need a Constants.h and a Constants.m. In the .h, declare these as `extern UIImage *kHamburgerImage;`. Then in the .m, remove the `static` keyword.

Comment: And I could still just import the `Constants.h` file and reference it as `kHamburgerImage`?

Comment: Hmmm... I put `#define kHamburgerImage extern UIImage *kHamburgerImage;` in my .h file and copied your code, removing the `static`, into a new .m file, and am getting `Expected expression` errors wherever I refer to it.

Comment: Is there anything else that needs to be in the .m file? `@implementation`?

Comment: Eh, giving up on this. Not worth it - I'll just check the OS version every time I reference it, and grab a different #define based on it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It will work now. Details get missed when typing all of this into SO without the benefit of a nice IDE.

Comment: OK, I'll try it again. Go source control!

Comment: Now I'm getting `Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_kHamburgerImage", referenced from:` linker errors for each file I reference it from.

Comment: Are the variables spelled the same in both the Constants.h and the Constants.m? Did you remove `static` from the variable in Constants.m? And is Constants.m targeted properly?

Comment: @Val No, this answer is not incorrect. Please explain why you think so.

Comment: @rmaddy I agree, you are right. Nanda's answer only works on different SDK of simulators. I deleted my previous comment.

Answer (score 6):

You can at least shorten your code by defining the iOS check as a macro.

```
#define IS_IOS7 [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion hasPrefix:@"7"]
```

And then your new code is way more readable,

```
if (IS_IOS7) {
    kHamburgerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal_menu_icon_portrait_ios7.png"];
} else {
    kHamburgerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal_menu_icon_portrait.png"];
}
```

Comment: It does work!  It just replaces IS_IOS7 with that following code at compile time.  It produces what would have been the unreadable code.

Answer (score 2):

You should use #ifndef instead of #ifdef. Here is the code . I hope it will help you.

```
#ifndef __IPHONE_7_0

#define kHamburgerImage [UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal_menu_icon_portrait_ios7.png"];

#else

#define kHamburgerImage [UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal_menu_icon_portrait.png"];

#endif
```

Comment: @Val No, there is no way this answer can work as expected. When the app is compiled, only one `kHamburgerImage` will be defined. So at runtime, no matter which version of iOS it is, that single value will be used by all versions.

Comment: @rmaddy I agree, you are right. This only works on different SDK of simulators.